# Could not cast value of type 'NSURL' to 'SocketIO.SocketManagerSpec

Tags: ios, socket.io, swift4

I am using `socket` in Swift 4 but getting this error on the line

```
 let url = URL(string: SOCKET_URL)
     let nsp = "log=\(true),forcePolling=\(true)"
     self.socket = SocketIOClient(manager: url! as! SocketManagerSpec,nsp:nsp)
     self.socket?.connect()   
     socket?.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
         print("socket connected")
     }
     socket?.on("currentAmount") {data, ack in
         guard let cur = data[0] as? Double else { return }
         self.socket?.emitWithAck("canUpdate", cur).timingOut(after: 0){data in
             self.socket?.emit("update", ["amount": cur + 2.50])
         }
         ack.with("Got your currentAmount", "dude")
     }
     socket?.connect()
 }
```

Please help, I stuck in this problem for the last two days.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to cast `URL` into `SocketManagerSpec`.

Please replace the line:

```
self.socket = SocketIOClient(manager: url! as! SocketManagerSpec,nsp:nsp)
```

with

```
self.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: url)
self.socket.nsp = nsp
```

Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: when i am using this then on firs line it shows with "self.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: url)" error-  "Missing argument for parameter 'nsp' in call" . and on second line   "self.socket?.nsp = nsp" error- "Cannot assign to property: 'nsp' is a 'let' constant".... @Litle Dev

Comment: "Cannot assign to property: 'nsp' is a 'let' constant" means `socket` is your `let` constant but I has to be `var` variable

Comment: i have done that but still error shows , and what about first line error it is not solved

Comment: Then please review your code with [simple example here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift)

Answer (score 0):

We can't make SocketManagerSpec object directly as normally we do for any object. So to make a socket we need to create manager and then we need to create socket with namespace

so replace

```
self.socket = SocketIOClient(manager: url! as! SocketManagerSpec,nsp:nsp)
```

with

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string:"http://192.x.x.x:3000")!)
var defaultNamespaceSocket : SocketIOClient!
var socket : SocketIOClient!

defaultNamespaceSocket = manager.defaultSocket
socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/swift")
```

Comment: Add some description with your solution

Comment: We can't make SocketManagerSpec object directly as normally we do for any object.  So to make a socket we need to create manager and then we need to create socket with namespace.